# Mocking a method with return type task

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, moq, mstest

I have a method with signature

```
Task<ResponseMessage> SaveToSQL(ConsumerModel obj)
```

I am trying to mock it using

```
_iIngestionRepository.Setup(m => m.SaveToSQL(model)).ReturnsAsync( new ResponseMessage() { });
```

below line throwing error

```
Task<ResponseMessage> result = _ingestionRepository.SaveToSQL(model);
  result.Result ///error
```

above code gives error on `result.Result` is always `null`

Comment: This is using Moq I assume? What is the error that is thrown?

Comment: iIngestionRepository.Setup(m => m.SaveToSQL(model)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new ResponseMessage()));

Comment: @VishalPawar No need, `ReturnsAsync` is better

Comment: @HItesh Kumar: I don't get you. Is issue in creating a mock Or Calling a method by creating new object?

Comment: The model in the setup is the same as the model in the actual call? You have defined your mock as strict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen if your `Setup`'s `model` is not exactly the same object as the `SaveToSQL` call's `model`.

```
_iIngestionRepository.Setup(m => m.SaveToSQL(modelA)).ReturnsAsync(new ResponseMessage());

Task<ResponseMessage> result = _ingestionRepository.SaveToSQL(modelB);
```

Either use the exact same instance (because under the hood there is a reference check).
Or use `It.IsAny` inside the `Setup` to accept any `ConsumerModel` instance:

```
_iIngestionRepository.Setup(m => m.SaveToSQL(It.IsAny<ConsumerModel>()))
                     .ReturnsAsync(new ResponseMessage());

var result = await _ingestionRepository.SaveToSQL(model);
```